# Multiple RewriteRules in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I cannot get my url rewriting to work. I have to root which works fine. But I'm trying to add another route and it doesn't work.

What I want is:

```
mydoma.in/
```

which routes to index.php

And then

```
mydoma.in/comments
```

which routes to page-with-comments.php

And this is my code so far:

```
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument
#ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 "Message"


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^comment/(.*)$ page-with-comments.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteBase /path/needed/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Both routes also takes parameters.

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: Sorry, updated content. Adding the second route doesnt work.

Comment: You used comment**s** in your link and comment in your rewrite rule (plural/singular). Is this just a typo?

Comment: You are enabling `RewriteEngine` **twice**, then you have a `RewriteBase /path/needed/` and you are trying to rewrite `/path/needed/comment/` to `/path/needed/page-with-comments.php` and `/path/needed/` to `/path/needed/index.php`. Remove the `RewriteBase` and move the `RewriteRule ^comment/(.*)$ page-with-comments.php/$1 [L]` inside the block `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteBase` seems to be faulty.

Have your code like this in root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^comment/(.*)$ page-with-comments.php/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```